# How to filter Pyspark column with binary data type?

Tags: pyspark, filter, binary

I have this dataframe (`df`)

```
|id |       binary_col          |
+-------------------------------+
|1  | [00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01] |
|2  | [00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01] |
|3  | [00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01] |
|4  | [00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02] |
|5  | [00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02] |
```

with these schema (`df.printSchema()`)

```
|-- id: int (nullable = true)
|-- binary_col: binary (nullable = true)
```

And I want to filter only the values with `[00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02]`

I've tried:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

- df.filter(F.col('binary_col')=='[00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02]')
- df.filter(F.col('binary_col')=='00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02')
```

but none of them worked.

When I try
 `df.filter(F.col('binary_col')==True)` I get the error that  `` cannot resolve '(`binary_col` = true)' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(`binary_col` = true)' (binary and boolean).; ``

Any thoughts?

Comment: how about `df.filter("binary_col = binary(2)")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unhex(<16 digit string>)` while filtering.

Here's an example using your data.

```
spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 2)]).toDF(['id', 'num']). \
    withColumn('num_as_bin', func.col('num').cast('binary')). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---+---+-------------------------+
# |id |num|num_as_bin               |
# +---+---+-------------------------+
# |1  |1  |[00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01]|
# |2  |1  |[00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01]|
# |3  |1  |[00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01]|
# |4  |2  |[00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02]|
# |5  |2  |[00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02]|
# +---+---+-------------------------+

# filter operation
spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 2)]).toDF(['id', 'num']). \
    withColumn('num_as_bin', func.col('num').cast('binary')). \
    filter(func.col('num_as_bin') == func.unhex(func.lit('0000000000000002'))). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---+---+-------------------------+
# |id |num|num_as_bin               |
# +---+---+-------------------------+
# |4  |2  |[00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02]|
# |5  |2  |[00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02]|
# +---+---+-------------------------+
```

OR, you could cast `2` as `long` and then `binary`. It yields the same result.

```
spark.sparkContext.parallelize([(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 2)]).toDF(['id', 'num']). \
    withColumn('num_as_bin', func.col('num').cast('binary')). \
    filter(func.col('num_as_bin') == func.lit(2).cast('long').cast('binary')). \
    show(truncate=False)
```